# Intercepting Windows messages with a global hook that application does not peeks or gets

Tags: c++, windows, windows-messages, setwindowshookex

I'm writing a global hook to listen to the Korean letter compositions. (You're not required to know how Korean letters are composed, please read through...)

The dll's code:

```cpp
#include <fstream>

#include "Header.h"

#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HHOOK get_message_hook = nullptr;
#pragma data_seg()

#pragma comment(linker, "/section:Shared,rws")
HINSTANCE dll_instance = nullptr;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        dll_instance = hModule;
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK callback(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (code < 0)
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(get_message_hook, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    std::ofstream output{ /*path to a file*/, std::ios::app };

    auto* param = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(lParam);
    if (param->message == WM_CHAR)
    {
        output << "WM_CHAR" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE)
    {
        output << "WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_IME_NOTIFY)
    {
        output << "WM_IME_NOTIFY" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_IME_COMPOSITION)
    {
        output << "WM_IME_COMPOSITION" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION)
    {
        output << "WM_IME_STARTCOMPOSITION" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION)
    {
        output << "WM_IME_ENDCOMPOSITION" << std::endl;
    }
    if (param->message == WM_IME_CHAR)
    {
        output << "WM_IME_CHAR" << std::endl;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(get_message_hook, code, wParam, lParam);
}

void DLL2_API set_hook()
{
    if (!get_message_hook)
    {
        get_message_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, callback, dll_instance, 0);
    }
}

void DLL2_API remove_hook()
{
    if (get_message_hook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(get_message_hook);
        get_message_hook = nullptr;
    }
}
```

The main:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "../Dll2/Header.h"


int main()
{
    char c;
    while (std::cin >> c)
    {
        if (c == 's')
        {
            set_hook();
        }
        else if (c == 'r')
        {
            remove_hook();
        }
    }

    remove_hook();
}
```

It works well with most of the applications, such as Notepad, Visual Studio, Discord, etc.
But when I type Korean letters on Chrome, it doesn't produce any of the messages above. I've also tried `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hooks but had no luck.

By reading the book [Subclassing and Hooking with Visual Basic](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/subclassing-and-hooking/0596001185/ch11.html), I understand that `WH_GETMESSAGE` hooks are called when the application calls `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`, and `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hooks are called when a message is sent directly to the application.

And by looking at the signature of the `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage`, you can filter the range of the messages you are willing to get/peek. I quickly wrote a simple program that gets only a certain range of messages and confirmed that the hooks can't get the messages other than the program listens to.

So my suspicion is that the Chrome is filtering out those messages while getting/peeking. Weird thing is, I'm not getting `WM_CHAR` messages either with Korean letters.

My question is,

1. Is my suspicion correct? (That the Chrome is filtering out the messages?)
2. Is there any way to 'intercept' messages an application is not getting or peeking?

Please note that `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` won't do the job since Korean typing system is not like latin alphabets.

Comment: It can be either that you hook to thing that does not receive input or that uses other means (like GetKeyState() or GetAsyncKeyState()) for getting input.

Comment: How are you verify whether or not your hook is being called?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Yep, that's what I'm suspecting. Is there any way to 'intercept' messages for those? I doubt a hook can do that, so is there any way to listen to a message that [some kind of low level system thing] tries to put on the current foreground window's message queue?

Comment: @Luke I've once logged every messages into a file regardless of their type to check if the hook was being called or not. I also used breakpoints.

Comment: Run process monitor on chrome to see if A) your DLL is getting injected and B) the output file is successfully being opened.